# HABTM: create and link to existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

**UPDATE:** I am so sorry. Many hours of trying to fix this problem got my brain off. Of course 'HABTM Checkboxes' railscast was the right answer to this post. As Dany said. Thank you.

---

I'm going into Ruby and Rails and got a problem I can't fix.

I have three tables in the database: `employees`, `departments`, and join-table `departments_employees`.

I use `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship:

```
#models/employee.rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :departments, :allow_destroy => true
   attr_accessible :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name, :departments_attributes
end

# models/department.rb
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

My problem is that I don't know how to create a new employee, link it to an existing department, and not create a new department at the same time.

Example:

```
Employee.create(:last_name => "Smith",
                :departments_attributes => [{:title => "IT"}])
```

But this creates both the employee and the department.

Is there any magic here to do that?

Comment: why an employee has many departments?

Comment: Because an employee can be in a several departments at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be deleting

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

Create a controller and views to enter departments (you can scaffold this) and use habtm to create employers and assign them departments via checkboxes.

For habtm have a look the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast)